# Azure B2C as external identity provider for Thinktecture Identity Server

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, azure-ad-b2c

I have a setup consisting of my relying party app -> thinktecture identity server -> azure ad b2c.  This is working as expected for login and signup using a signin or signup policy.  The issue I am running into is that the password reset link on azure b2c page is sending back to my thinktecture identity server, instead of to azure b2c where it should go?  Has any one encountered this and found a solution?  I am also unable to submit a profile edit policy request to azure b2c through thinktecture identity server.  My thinktecture identity server instance, just sees that the user is logged in and returns them directly back to my relying party.

So my questions are this...

1. How do I get the password reset functionality working correctly fron azure b2c?
2. How can I handle profile edit requests from my relying party and pass it in appropriately in thinktecture identity server?

It was suggested that I use ACR_values, but I don't see how that is going to help any.  Any suggestions/ideas would be helpful as I seem to have run up against a brick wall here.